# Shortcut image files to html website locally

Tags: html, image, shortcut

Hi i am making my own website. And make alot of copies, do some changes. to see what version I like best. But this takes up space on the HD. And I have a small ssd.

Is it possible to put a shortcut to my images folder in all my versions? So all my versions only contain the html files.

I have all my image files stored in a sub folder to the html files.

Comment: If your images folder is a sub-folder of where the html pages are, the page to the images would just be: `images/fileName.ext`

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new "website" only containing images, you can even call it images. And then in all your website versions you will access images via general url like http://localhost/images/

Comment: The problem is mostly on my ssd. Not when i upload them to a web server since i upload just one copy there. Didn't get your link to work there. Maybe because it has a public_html folder. I am using freehosting.com